# In Array with regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I`m using $_POST array with results of checkbox's selected from a form.

I'm thinking of using  php `in_array` function but how could I extract only values that start with **chk** Given the following array:

```
Array ( 
        [chk0] => 23934567622639616 
        [chk3] => 23934567622639618 
        [chk4] => 23934567622639619 
        [select-all] => on 
        [process] => Process
      )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried writing an algorithm to do this yet? I'm interested to see how far you got on your own ...

Comment: if you named your inputs `chk[]` instead of `chk0-1-2-3` etc they would live in there own neat array

Comment: You might want to look at array_keys() or array_flip() and preg_grep().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and fast

```
$result=array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

    if(substr($key, 0, 2) == 'chk'){
         $result[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do this, I like [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter).

#### Example:

```
$result = array_filter(
    $_POST,
    function ($key) {
        return strpos($key, "chk") === 0;
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution from http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

```
<?php
function preg_grep_keys($pattern, $input, $flags = 0) {
    return array_intersect_key($input, array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input), $flags)));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$ary = array_filter($originalArray,
         function($key){ return preg_match('/chk/', $key); },
         ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY 
 );
```